# Flexible survival models in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Is it possible to fit flexible hazard models in R with prespecifying a hazard function? For example I have a data generating process I know it results in a U-shaped hazard function. How can I fit a flexible parametric model (and get the corresponding estimates)?

I know that `flexsurv` can fit spline hazard models but I can't get it to fit a known shape hazard function model. Any help or example would be very welcome.

Comment: Are you willing to use JAGS or BUGS? The R survival libraries, while extremely powerful, tend to be designed for specific problems with specific types of hazard rates.

Comment: I am open to JAGS or BUGS, however I haven't really used them before. Just played a bit with them. An resources or information would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Let me try to construct a toy example, with references and links. In the meantime, let us see whether someone else gives you a quicker/easier answer. Is your data censored?

Comment: yes, the data is censored. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add some details about the hazard function you would like to the question?

Comment: For example U-shaped, bath-tube shaped or a combination of various time varying hazard functions http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2288989

Answer (score 3):

My answer cheats a bit by not using R on its own, but using tools that can be run from within R. What you want to do is fairly advanced survival analysis, and I doubt that any of the existing R packages will be flexible enough for you.

The example below is based on the code on [Brad Carlin's software page](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~brad/software.html), provided as an addendum to their paper on Joint Survival models.<sup>1</sup> Joint models lead to fairly complicated likelihoods, so this method should be able to handle a lot of what you want to achieve.

It uses the BUGS "ones trick", as explained in the WinBUGS user manual.<sup>2</sup> The ones trick can also be used in JAGS, which I will use since it supports more platforms. The code can be used to fit an arbitrary survival function, given it can be integrated analytically. In theory, more complex hazard rates can also be handled using MCMC techniques, but you will then have to write your own MCMC sampler from scratch and use numerical integration techniques (or for your combination of various time varying hazard functions).

First, the R code to call the model:

```R
library(rjags) # To enable JAGS within R

JAGSlist <- list("N" = N,         # number of observations
                 "event" = event, # 1 for event, zero for censor
                 "T" = T          # Survival time
)

#Construct the model
my.jags.model <- jags.model("MyJAGSmodel.jags",
                        JAGSlist,n.chains = 1,
                        n.adapt = 100)
my.results = coda.samples(my.jags.model, 
                          c("alpha","beta"), # parameters to monitor
                          n.iter = 10000)

my.results <- my.results[[1]] #To unlist it
summary(my.results)
```

Next, the contents of the MyJAGSmodel.jags file:

```jags
data{
      for (i in 1:N){
            ones[i] <- 1
      }     
}

model{
    for (i in 1:N) {

    q[i]<-L[i]/C 
    ones[i]~dbern(q[i])
    # Likelihood for survival data 
    # event=1 if event, and 0 if censoring
     L[i]<-pow(h[i],event[i])*S[i] 

    # Hazard for individual i at their survival time
    # This is where we specify it as U-shaped (quadratic)
     h[i] <- alpha*T[i] + beta*(T[i]^2)

    # Cumulative hazard H[t] = int_0^t (h[u] du)
     H[i] <- (alpha)*(1/2)*(T[i]^2) + (beta)*(1/3)*(T[i]^3)

    # Survival probability for individual i 
    # at their survival time
     S[i]<-exp(-H[i])

    # Density function
     f[i]<-h[i]*S[i]

    }  

C<- 10000000 # part of trick

#priors
#Parameters of interest
alpha~dnorm(0,1.0E-6)
beta~dnorm(0,1.0E-6)
}
```

As you can see, the code constructs the actual likelihood used by survival models (for details about this, why not ask a question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)?!) 
You can also use [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/), which has an `increment_log_likelihood` function, so it doesn't require the tricks used by JAGS to increment the log likelihood. It can also be called from R. If you would like the Stan code, let me know or post another question.
You will have to experiment with this and see whether it works for your scenario. What you want to do is pretty advanced survival analysis, and you may have to write your own MCMC sampler if you want to try more flexible hazard rates. See Gilks et al (1996)<sup>3</sup> for a good primer.

A great place to see models fitted with JAGS is at [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.co.uk/), and in the book that the site is based on.<sup>4</sup>

---

**Update**, just in case people are still visiting this question.

I have been working on a Stan survival example, which will hopefully work in a lot of cases, find it here. It is a work in progress, but the code should be usable. I am trying to explain my workings there (the statistics bit, as well as the Stan bit):

https://github.com/dwcoder/StanSurvivalBoilerplate

---

<sup>1</sup>Guo, X., Carlin, B. P.: **Separate and Joint Modeling of Longitudinal and Event Time Data Using Standard Computer Packages**, *The American Statistician* 58(1), 16–24, 2004

<sup>2</sup>Spiegelhalter, D., Thomas, A., Best, N., Lunn, D.: **WinBUGS user manual**. See chapter on *Advance use of BUGS language.*

<sup>3</sup>Gilks, W.R., Richardson, S., Spiegelhalter, D.: **Markov Chain Monte Carlo in Practice**, Taylor & Francis, 1996

<sup>4</sup>Kruschke, J. K. (2011). **Doing bayesian data analysis**.

Comment: Thanks. This is all very new to me.

Comment: Sure thing. I think your question is actually more a statistical one than it is one of programming, so I think you should really go visit Cross Validated if you get stuck. It sits in between the worlds of stats and programming, though, because you have the survival analysis theory, and then the tools that estimate its parameters. Despite having been around for a while there isn't a fixed solution. You can hack JAGS or Stan like I showed, and maybe the tools will get there one day, but you are very close to exploring unfamiliar territory. This is a good topic for a Masters degree. :)

Comment: This is excellent. I know it's been a year since you posted this but any chance for you to add an addendum with STAN code? That system seems to have odd ways of dealing with censorship compared to JAGS. So it would be great to see an example like this done there.

Comment: Glad it helped! Yeah, censorship is always a tricky one. In 2014 Stan added the ability to add user-defined functions, which makes this a lot easier. I have been working on a Stan survival example, which will hopefully work in a lot of cases, find it [here](https://github.com/dwcoder/StanSurvivalBoilerplate). It is a work in progress, but the code should be usable. I am trying to explain my workings there (the statistics bit, as well as the Stan bit). I will see if I can also add a short addendum to this question.

Comment: It's weird, I never noticed that you could declare a function{} block inside of a Stan. That really upends my thinking about how input models in the system.

Comment: It is a pretty new feature. But it greatly extends Stan's power.